# Azure Logic Apps: "When a work item is created" trigger fires endlessly even when no item is created

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I am automating some behaviors in azure devops using logic apps in Visual studio. One of the flows is to create a work item when a different work item type is created. The issue is that the flow trigger fires endlessly while only one work item is created

I have tried the following:
* Delete the app and redeploy it
* Delete the resource group and all its contents, create a new project and redeploy it

[The full flow criteria](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao33RnBtvf9Zgj4D1xCaMwe2hIM1)

[The flow runs more than it should](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao33RnBtvf9Zgj0PhHKma9MTrN2A)

Update 1:

I did notice that the app triggers endlessly but only for the work items created after its deployment. So, it ignores all previously created work items

Comment: Actually I think it's cause by the action Create a work item, in the result it looks it only created one item, actually every time it's triggered it will create a same item then replace the old one, then it will be seen as a new item. Maybe you could add a guid to the item name.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#guid

Comment: Yes, this could be the case if the work item type of the trigger action and the one created are the same but they are different types.The trigger is "Test Case" and creates "Test Integration"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a 'Condition' after 'When a work item is created 2', perhaps the trigger condition on the field Type does not work as expected on that datatype? I worked on a case where the 'sql get-rows' where would either return everything or nothing because the connector only supported a specific type of DateTime.

So a condition that would check for the value of Type to be "Test Sales" before moving on to the initialize variable.

Comment: Yes, I added a flag to the work item type and the condition checks for this flag. Although, it is not stable but it is a good workaround. The issue now would be in the number of executions which would cost much more.